# New Starting number for sales_flat_order entity_id

Tags: orders, entities, integrate

How is the sales_flat_order.entity_id determined and is there a safe way for me to start it at a higher number?

We just changed versions of magento and have an external ERP. Becuase the orders are created using entity_id we are getting duplicate order issues. I would like to start entity_id where the last site left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This information is stored in `eav_entity_store` and can be edited there.</strike>

To change the entity_id you need to change the AUTO_INCREMENT value of a database, this can be done via a SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```

On a short search through the magento codebase and Varien_Ddl and Pdo stuff I didn't found anything to do it via a method.

Comment: Hmm I'm using 1.8 and it's not there. I'm not looking for 'increment_last_id' but am looking for 'entity_id'.

Comment: oh, sorry. Updated.